# NFS protocol problem

Tags: mount, nfs, protocols

I tried to configure a NFS server with my Red Pitaya board, with a custom Ubuntu image, exactly as this page tells me to https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu-16-04. 
However when I try to mount my directories on my Client I got this error:

```
sudo mount 10.30.xx.xxx:/var/nfs/general /nfs/general
mount.nfs: Protocol not supported
```

Where 10.30.xx.xxx is my Host's IP. I googled this error and found that executing this command  in my Host should tell me the allowed Protocols of my NFS service, so I got his:

```
rpcinfo 10.30.xx.xxx |egrep "service|nfs"
   program version netid     address                service    owner
    100003    2    tcp       0.0.0.0.8.1            nfs        superuser
    100003    3    tcp       0.0.0.0.8.1            nfs        superuser
    100003    4    tcp       0.0.0.0.8.1            nfs        superuser
    100003    2    udp       0.0.0.0.8.1            nfs        superuser
    100003    3    udp       0.0.0.0.8.1            nfs        superuser
    100003    4    udp       0.0.0.0.8.1            nfs        superuser
    100003    2    tcp6      ::.8.1                 nfs        superuser
    100003    3    tcp6      ::.8.1                 nfs        superuser
    100003    4    tcp6      ::.8.1                 nfs        superuser
    100003    2    udp6      ::.8.1                 nfs        superuser
    100003    3    udp6      ::.8.1                 nfs        superuser
    100003    4    udp6      ::.8.1                 nfs        superuser
```

I proceed to use the option vers (and nolock because the console tells me to) but still got the same error with all 3 versions (vers=2,vers=3,vers=4)

```
mount -o rw,nolock,vers=2 10.30.xx.xxx:/var/nfs/general /nfs/general
mount.nfs: Protocol not supported
```

How come all 3 versions are not supported? Am I using the options wrong?